# Box.net URL Schemes

Tags: box-api

I'm writing an iPhone app, MyApp, which needs access to documents on and off-line.  My users are already managing these documents (pdf's, movies, etc) via the Box iPhone app synching with the company server.

If MyApp knows the path & filename of a document, is it possible to use the Box URL Schemes to launch Box and open the document externally?

MyApp doesn't need to store or access the files and since Box already has the files downloaded, there's no point storing them in the Document space of both apps.

If there is such a URL Scheme, two follow up questions are: A) is there a callback to return to MyApp when the document is closed, and B) can MyApp use another URL Scheme to get a list of documents?

```
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"box://some/path/to/fileid?callback=myapp://"];
if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL]) {
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
}
```

If this isn't currently possible, but of interest to Box, I'm interested in being a beta tester/early adopter.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to direct the user to a Box page, you may be able to direct the user to a specific file in one of two ways:

1) If the file is shared in Box and you have the shared name, you can generate a shared url (see sharing in the docs at developers.box.com).  This only works for files that were shared, however.

2) If you have the file id of the file in Box, you can generate a URL to which the user can login to one's Box account and view the content.  You can determine that URL by going into Box and seeing how URLs are displayed when you click on a particular file.  We don't like to advertise that URL for developers, however, because we don't guarantee that this URL format will be maintained in the future.  It hasn't changed in a while, so it's probably safe to use, but Box provides that "use it at your own risk" disclaimer.

Unfortunately, Box doesn't have a way to pull up a file based on file path.  You need the file id or shared name.  There isn't a url that relies on file or folder names.

Comment: I have access to the file id's in MyApp.  What would the url be?  `NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"box://s/zigfha60rm3ntz272gmp"];`?  MyApp launches the Box app, I'm but not sure how to structure the url to open the file.

Comment: If I do `http://box.com/files/0/f/[folder_id]/1/f_[file_id]` it will open it in a browswer (which defeats the purpose of being offline). If I try `box://files/0/f/[folder_id]/1/f_[file_id]` it'll open the box app, but wont access the file.  If I try `box.com://files/0/f/[folder_id]/1/f_[file_id]` it wont find the Box app on my iPad.  I have Box 2.8.1 installed.

Comment: For future visitors: Box now has deeplinking published as part of their API documentation https://box-content.readme.io/v2.0/docs/deep-linking-to-box-mobile-apps